# DialogFragments and findFragmentById

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

I have this app with a common activity and several different fragments replaced into the same layout ID: `R.id.content`

Some of the fragments are normal support.v4.Fragment and some are from v4.DialogFragment

On tablets, DialogFragments are shown as Dialogs and on phones they're normally included in the `R.id.content`

So usually if I want to find out which fragment is current, it's easy to call

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
```

but the DialogFragments issued are Dialogs are not on the `R.id.content`, AFAIK they're not even in the same Window.

So the question is: is there any "framework level" way to locate the dialog fragments? I mean, is there a way to do it without having to manually keeping reference of Fragments (or their tags) ?

Comment: Why isn't the tag enough?

Comment: because I'm already using tag to identify type and ID of content. A third layer or information in a single string would complicate stuff even more.

Comment: May I know do you mean identify type and ID?

Comment: type: photo, photo stream, content stream, user profile, comments page, like page, etc. ID: a number

Comment: You could create an interface that provides this data and let all your fragments (using a base fragment) implement this interface and probably make these stuff more systematic.

Comment: But the reason they're in the tag is so I can use findFragmentByTag to locate specific fragments on my stack. And I'm sorry, do you have an answer to the actual question? Even if it's "it's not possible" ?